# SW2URDF - urdf .stl files not found

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ive used SW2URDF to export a urdf but every time I get errors stating the models cannot be found.  Ive been at this for 2 days straight, the models are in fact there and there isnt any discrepancy in path or file name, case is correct.  Ive poured over the forum and tried everything from changing the filepath to complelety reinstalling ros, move it and reconfiguring workspace.  im running ubunto 16.04 and kinetic  any insight would be appreciated:

```
[ERROR] [1527370549.957216539]: Error retrieving file [package://AR2urdf/meshes/base_link.STL]: Package [AR2urdf] does not exist
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292375/sw2urdf---urdf-.stl-files-not-found/) by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-27**:
The easiest way to help you would be to show us your package. If you can upload it to github or some other service someone can take a look.

As to the error you show: that is a generic error telling you that for some reason, the resource retriever library can't find a pkg by that name. Have you ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-27**:
.. build your workspace and done a `source /path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` before trying to start any launch files (or load your urdf in some other way)?

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
Ive built my workspace and run the setup.bash as you point out.  I think I have it all setup correctly but ROS and linux are new to me.  Ive had so many requests-comments about ROS im trying to learn this quickly.  I placed the urdf file created by SW2URDF to the project repository here:

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
https://github.com/Chris-Annin/AR2
thank you for your help btw

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-27**:\

> and run the setup.bash

you cannot 'run it'. You must use `source /path/to/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
correct - I entered the command `source /home/chris/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-27**:
Ok. And after you've done that, what is the output of `rospack find AR2urdf`?

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
[rospack] Error: package 'AR2urdf' not found

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
I had the urdf in my home folder.  I just moved it to the ros share folder and now the output is `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/AR2urdf`  moveit now opened the file with no issues.  I did have the urdf in the share folder previously with the same errors.  I assume a combination of not having my workspace

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
setup correctly followed by not moving the urdf to a place within the ros folder was this issue?  than you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> [rospack] Error: package 'AR2urdf' not found
> ```

This is the cause of the `Error retrieving file` errors you are getting.

Looking at your package manifest I know why:

```
<package>
  <name>AR2urdf</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <description>
    <p>URDF Description package for AR2urdf</p>
    <p>This package contains configuration data, 3D models and launch files
for AR2urdf robot</p>
  </description>
  <author>me</author>
  <maintainer email="me2email.com" />
  <license>BSD</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roslaunch</build_depend>
  <run_depend>robot_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rviz</run_depend>
  <run_depend>joint_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>gazebo</run_depend>
  <export>
    <architecture_independent />
  </export>
</package>
```

Look at the `email` attribute of the `maintainer` element: `me2email.com` is not a valid email address.

If I ask `catkin_tools` to list the pkgs in a workspace with just your package, I get this:

```
Error: The directory /catkin_ws/src contains an invalid package. See below for details:

Invalid email "me2email.com" for person ""
Warning: Catkin package name "AR2urdf" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, and underscores.
```

Correcting the email address immediately solves this.

I'm pretty sure correcting your email address, rebuilding your workspace, re`source`ing `devel/setup.bash` and then trying again will make things work.

---

Edit: you *must* have seen errors while building your workspace. If I do not correct the email address and try to run `catkin_make`, I get this:

```
Base path: /catkin_ws
Source space: /catkin_ws/src
Build space: /catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /catkin_ws/install
WARNING: Catkin package name "AR2urdf" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, and underscores.
Invalid email "me2email.com" for person ""
```

It doesn't even try to build the package.

Which `setup.bash` file did you source in your workspace?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
I didnt see any errors this time but moving the file to the ros share directory and then re entering `source /home/chris/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` seemed to do the trick.  the robot is now open in moveit.  thank you for your help.  Im not sure I would have made much progress without you sending

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
me in the right direction.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-27**:\

> moving the file to the ros share directory

where did you move what file exactly?

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
I moved the `AR2urdf.urdf` file into `opt/ros/kinetic/share` directory.  when you had me check `rospack find AR2urdf` and it could not find it I made the assumption that the urdf files needed to be within the ROS directory - is this correct or did this not matter?  thank you.

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-05-27**:
I obviously have a lot to learn - this is very foreign to me.  Im going through some ROS tutorials on catkin and cmake now.  let me know if you know of any other resources I should be studying.  thanks again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-28**:
re: `/opt/ros/kinetic/share`: rule of thumb: don't ever touch directories under `/opt/ros`, or at least, don't manually move files there. It should not be necessary and if you do think it's necessary, something is wrong. Until you get a better grasp of things, don't touch those directories.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-28**:
Always pay attention to the output of commands on the command line. The fact that you "got the prompt back" does not mean everything is ok.

re: lot to learn: realise that ROS *uses* a lot of other tools. There are very few things really ROS-specific. Catkin ~= CMake. Find a CMake tutorial and ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-28**:
.. then come back to ROS/Catkin. You'll find a lot of 'magic incantations' will have become clear.

Same with programming: if you don't have any C++/Python experience, *don't* try to learn programming *and* ROS at the same time. It can be very confusing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-28**:\

> I didnt see any errors this time but moving the file to the ros share directory [..]

Moving the file was not necessary after we fixed the error(s). Please remove the file again.